# Complex integration using the residue theorem $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^4+1}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I've beat my head against a wall with this one for the last couple days. Evaluate:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^4+1}\,dx$$

I factored the denominator using Euler's identity such that the roots are $$x=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}, \frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}, \frac{-1-i}{\sqrt2}, \frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}$$

I know that we can apply the residue theorem and calculate and sum the residues in the top half of $\mathbb{C}$ to get our solution to the integral. I set
$$H(z)=\frac{ze^{iz}}{(z-(\frac {-1-i}{\sqrt2}))(z-(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}))}$$

and $$f(z)=\frac{H(z)}{(z-(\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}))(z-(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}))}$$

But when I try to proceed from here to take the residue I am not sure that I have the right setup and quickly get lost in the algebra, could someone please let me know if I am at least on the right path?

Comment: Using residue theorem for this is definitely the best way to go since it's the simplest, but just for fun if you also wanted an alternative method that uses reals only - you could do the method I did in this link (same integral essentially): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745273/solving-int-infty-infty-fracx-sin3xx41-dx-without-complex-i/3745352#3745352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(z)=\dfrac{ze^{iz}}{z^4+1}$, then$$\operatorname{res}_{z=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}}\bigl(g(z)\bigr)=\frac{\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}i\right)}{4\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)^3}=-\frac14ie^{-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}}$$and$$\operatorname{res}_{z=\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}}\bigl(g(z)\bigr)=\frac{\left(\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}i\right)}{4\left(\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)^3}=\frac{1}{4} i e^{-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}}.$$So, and since $\exp\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\pm\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\left(\cos\left(\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)+\sin\left(\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)i\right)$, the sum of the residues is\begin{multline}\require{cancel}-\frac14i\exp\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)+\frac14i\exp\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)=\\=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)}4\left(\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)-\cancel{\cos\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)i}+\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)+\cancel{\cos\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)i}\right)=\\=\frac12e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\end{multline}and therefore$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm dx=\pi ie^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right).$$So,\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm dx&=\operatorname{Im}\left(\pi ie^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right)\\&=\pi e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right).\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive solution, it shed some light on techniques that I was unaware of. This may be incredibly simple but how were you able to sum the two residues together? Eventually I get what resembles a $sinh(\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}})$ function and we know $i~sinh(x)=sin(ix)$. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: I have expanded my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In terms of $z_\pm:=\tfrac{\pm1+i}{2}$ your integral is $\Im I$ with$$I:=\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{xe^{ix}dx}{x^4+1}=2\pi i\sum_\pm\lim_{z\to z_\pm}\frac{z(z-z_\pm)e^{iz}}{z^4+1}.$$By L'Hôpital's rule,$$I=2\pi i\sum_\pm\left.\frac{(iz^2+(2-iz_\pm)z-z_\pm)e^{iz}}{4z^3}\right|_{z_\pm}=\frac{\pi i}{2}\sum_\pm\frac{e^{iz_\pm}}{z_\pm^2}.$$So your integral is$$\frac{\pi}{2}\Re\left[\frac{e^{(-1+i)/\sqrt{2}}}{i}+\frac{e^{(-1-i)/\sqrt{2}}}{-i}\right]=\pi e^{-1\sqrt{2}}\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$